# Recover password in windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows, data-recovery, windows-server-2008-r2, password-recovery

I want to recover my password i n windows 2008 i searched i n google and find many way to recover.So in all of theme say that we should run this command:

```
  C:\
    cd windows\system32
    ren utilman.exe utilman.exe.bak
    copy cmd.exe utilman.exe
```

But i don have utilman.exe .and also i try to move utilman.exe .So how can i Recover password in windows 2008 R2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll need to repair the O/S, if you to run sfc /scannow first then repair via the media if need be or you can do it manually via shell here:

http://www.howtogeek.com/106333/how-to-reset-your-forgotten-domain-admin-password-on-server-2008-r2/

Comment: Btw I think you posted in the wrong forum too, Serverfault is the one.